# how to check name servers are pointing to my server IP

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver, dns-zone

I have an application in node.js on a VPS(Cent OS 6.6) and I have set the port to 80.
the problem I'm having is that the zone I have created in my DNS server doesn't work. I have created the name servers and added them to my domain, but still my domain doesn't point to the IP.
so my question is, how to check if My name servers are actually pointing to my IP? like an Online service that you enter the name servers and it tells you that which server is listening to that.
thanks a lot

Comment: We can't help you without knowing the domain name.

Comment: funila.ir is the domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to check nameservers is to **dig** it or **ping** it.

You will have to just fire following commands from terminal.

dig n1.yournameservers.com
ping n1.yournameservers.com

Result of above commands should show your IP address.

Currently your website is using nameservers of cloudflare:

clark.ns.cloudflare.com.   ['173.245.59.87']
mona.ns.cloudflare.com.   ['173.245.58.206']

Upon checking DNS lookup of your website, I come to know that A record is missing at DNS zone. Once you create A record with web server IP address, your website should start working.